# Dialog box rendering issue - close button has strange blue rectangle border around it

Tags: jquery-ui

The below code draws a lager blue rectangle border around a close button. It only happens in Chrome. The chrome is Version 46.0.2490.86 
I tried playing with CSS styling but didn't help. The below sample code is from jQuery.com site. I am a novice in area of HTML,CSS, and jQuery, so please provide detailed answer that would help me to resolve the issue. Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this css code:

```
.ui-button:focus { outline:none !important }
```

Comment: This stumped me for a long time. Thanks!